# Only first button expands on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I just recently started picking up javascript/angular and html and I am making a table, and I want to add drop down menus within the table that expand to bigger descriptions.  I added a table and I used "ng-repeat" in order to populate the table.  I also added my button which can collapse and expand, but when I click on any of the buttons, only the first button expands.  So even if I click the 2nd, 3rd, etc. it only opens the first drop down.

How can I make it so the corresponding button expands the correct description?  I'm not sure if it's the "ng-repeat" that is making it not work as intended.  I think it might have to do with the id of the buttons.  So is there a way to give each one a unique id, or to get rid of it altogether so that the correct button opens the correct description?

Here is the code:

```
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees| filter:searchText" >
                    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Last}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="FAQ">
                            <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">+</a>
                            <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">-</a>
                            <div class="question"> {{employee.Gender}} </div>
                            <div class="list">
                                <p>THIS IS A DESCRIPTION </p>
                                <p>MORE DESCRIPTION</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is the css stylesheet:

```
/*stuff for button press description*/
.FAQ { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    height:auto !important; 
}
.list {
    display:none; 
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
.show {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:inline; 
}
.hide, .show {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    background: #cccbbb;
    opacity: .95;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.hide:hover, .show:hover {
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #222 inset;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.list p{
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
}
.question {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 200%;
}

button.btn.collapsed:before
{
    content:'+' ;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
}
button.btn:before
{
    content:'-' ;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ng-repeat` you should have access to an `$index` variable within your repeat block that you can use to assign specific id's within the code.  So you can set your `id='hide-{{$index}}`.

Another thing you can do is to toggle a boolean associated with your model and do a

```
ng-show='employee.ShowDetails'
```

that is toggled with a

```
ng-click='employee.ShowDetails = !employee.ShowDetails'
```

Comment: '$index' was exactly what I was looking for and was an instant fix to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The ng repeater is creating multiple divs with the same class, and no differentiation in the URI targeted by your css.  When your href is clicked the css pattern:

```
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:inline; 
}
```

...is targeting the div with class "list" preceded by the URI.  Well that matches as many divs in your DOM that were output by the repeater, as the URI is identical across all repeated elements, so the first is used.

In the repeater do:

```
 <a href="#hide{{$index}}" class="hide" id="hide{{$index}}">+</a>
 <a href="#show{{$index}}" class="show" id="show{{$index}}">-</a>
```

That will change the URI and the ID that self references, while allowing you to keep the (freaky) .hide:target ~ .list syntax.